# Can I accelerate mouse sensetivity over the standard maximum?

Tags: gnome, xorg, mouse

I've used "Mouse Preferences" window to set mouse pointer acceleration and sensitivity sliders to their maximums, but I am still not satisfied with how fast does mouse pointer move (I've got a very big display). Can I accelerate it over?

Comment: I've been trying to do the opposite: decrease the sensitivity below the minimum. Have you had any luck with your attempts?

Comment: No, I hadn't. I had to adapt myself :-(

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure what the range of the mouse acceleration sliders are, but you can easily change this manually by using `xset`.

Try something like `xset m 100 5`, that makes it go *very* fast for me.

The syntax of the command is:

```
xset m <pixels to move when going fast> <pixels threshold before moving fast>
```

To make the changes stick, put them in your `~/.xinitrc`

Comment: Does not help. Even after "xset m 1000 3" I can't feel any difference. I use Ubuntu 10.10 with Logitech M-BT58 USB mouse. I also have built-in PS/2 touchpad in my laptop, but it does not get much faster also.

Comment: @Ivan: I'm running Kubuntu 10.10 so I assumed it would be the same for Ubuntu. I can't really figure out why it would be any different for Ubuntu though. Can you try `xset m 50 1` instead? I'm not sure where the limits are but `1000 3` doesn't do much for me either.

Comment: @Ivan - it may be getting overwritten by gnome-settings-daemon or similar. You can use `xset q` before and after to see if it is having any effect. Also, do you have more than one pointing device (mouse, trackpad, ball) attached to your computer ?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this is the right approach, but changing the ***AccelerationProfile*** from 0 to 6 and setting the ***VelocityScale*** to 10 you can get a really quick pointer. Much faster than if you change it in "*Mouse Preferences*". Here's how to do it:

First, you need to find your mouse ID and ProductName :

```
xinput list
...
 Logitech USB Optical Mouse                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
...
```

Now you can set the AccelerationProfile to 6 with this command :

```
xinput set-prop 11 "Device Accel Profile" 6
# 11 = DEVICE_ID
# 6 = linear (more speed, more acceleration)
```

Then you set the VelocityScale to what suits you. (1 to 10) (Higher = Faster):

```
xinput set-prop 11 "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 5
```

If the above solution works for you, you can make it persistent by editing your xorg.conf (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`). Add this section at the end of the file.

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier      "Logitech"                   # Whatever you want.
   MatchProduct    "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" # ProductName from xinput list.
   Option          "AccelerationProfile" "6"
   Option          "VelocityScale" "5"
EndSection
```

Once you reboot, you should have the same result as with the xinput command.

Let me know if it helps.

*** *Tested with Ubuntu 10.10 ****

*References* :

- man xorg.conf InputDevice Section
- http://xorg.freedesktop.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration