# Mouse sensitivity to low

Tags: 11.10, mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I accelerate mouse sensetivity over the standard maximum?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5092/can-i-accelerate-mouse-sensetivity-over-the-standard-maximum)

I want to increase mouse sensitivty above the maximum in Ubuntu 11.10, since even that is way too low for me. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Just open up your dashboard and type in "Mouse". You should see a program called "Mouse and Touchpad". Click it, and you can adjust plenty of settings for your Mouse!